# Database value not displayed in combo box in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox

```
    Try


        sqlstr = "select lti_no,loc_code,to_loc,issue_Date,status,supplier_code,remarks,total_pack,total_loose from pos_lti_out_hdr where lti_no='" & srch & "'"

        Dim da As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim searchresult As New DataTable
        Dim DS As DataSet
        da = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlstr, AppsCon)
        da.Fill(searchresult)
        If searchresult.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            txtfrmlocation.Text = searchresult.Rows(0)("loc_code").ToString
            txtremarks.Text = searchresult.Rows(0)("remarks").ToString
            txttransferdate.Text = searchresult.Rows(0)("issue_date").ToString
            cmbtolocation.Text = searchresult.Rows(0)("to_loc").Tostring
            cmbstatus.Text = searchresult.Rows(0)("status").ToString
            txttotalqty.Text = searchresult.Rows(0)("total_pack").ToString
            txttotalloose.Text = searchresult.Rows(0)("total_loose").ToString
```

The above code retrieves the values from the database but it does not bind the data for the selected record to the combobox. The combo box displays only blank values. In debug mode there are values in the dataset for the columns but in combo box it is not displayed.
I dont know what i am doing wrong.  The field in database is to_loc. I will attach also the debug code as it shows only zero items.But in dataset its present.[image][image]

Comment: I guess first you have to populate the combobox. Have you populated it like `cmbtolocation.AddItem('...')` then you can use `cmbtolocation.text = '...'`

Comment: no.. actually i don't want to populate with a list of values.. i want to display whichever value is there in the particular column to be displayed in the combobox. now as you can see there is one more combo box called status in the code which displays the correct value from the database.for eg. if status is new in database it displays new in the code also.but the same is not happening for the other combo box cmbtolocation? why?

Comment: That combobox is a gridview column not a standalone one but anyway why not debug it with the same value as in the `cmbstatus`. Try adding this value to it and see if it works.

Comment: I am afraid you have to use `combo.addItem(...)`

Comment: Try add watch to your **cmbtolocation.Text**. See how the value changed. I assume some other event updated/changed the value after your have populate it from the DB.

Comment: hi the issue is resolved. it was a simple property which was giving an issue. the drop down style of the combo box was drop down list. I changed it to drop down.Now the value is getting displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the drop down style of the combo box to  drop down  resolved the issue. 
The style was drop down list.